# Google Analytics Android version code and version name

Tags: android, google-analytics

Why am I seeing 2 different statistics for the same app version in Google Analytics?
Am I supposed to sum them up or do they overlap?
[image: Google Analytics screenshot app version 37 or 2.2.0]

build.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    versionCode 37
    versionName "2.2.0"
  }
}
// ...
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
}
```

I'm using Firebase + TagManager implementation